# Where do I submit "Stack Overflow Chat" feature requests & bug reports?

Tags: discussion, chat

Apparently, "[Stack Overflow Chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/)" is still a work in progress.

**Where is the best place to submit feature requests & bug reports?**

Is the best place:

- With a [new question here on Meta](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/ask)?   (like [bug](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/bug)/[feature-request](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/feature-request) for the main site)
- With the stack overflow [contact form](https://stackoverflow.com/contact)?
- In the [chat sandbox](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/1/sandbox), as hinted [here](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/faq#fascinating-but-i-have-a-question-about-):

[image: img]

---

**For example:**

> - I'd like to see the **maximum time in which a chat message can be deleted** increased from 2min to at least 10min. Perhaps a room owner should be able to delete a message indefinitely.

---

## EDIT:

I just realized there are 87 [questions in Meta tagged `(chat)`+`(feature-request)`](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/chat+feature-request) and 99 [questions in Meta tagged `(chat)`+`(bug)`](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/chat+bug), so I suppose that's my answer...?

I may as well leave this question open briefly in case there's any related comment...

Comment: did you also realized that chat feature request is often answered "sorry chat is not a priority" ;) As advice don't loose your time asking chat feature SO don't care and almost never answer at all.

Comment: You can post on your own site meta (so this one is fine) or post on MSE if your feature is across  sites (and that applies to chat).

Comment: Thanks. @rene I'm curious if you agree with Stargateur?  I suppose it would make sense since there aren't many users. (last night, for example, there were 28 users in 20 rooms)

Comment: I'm not that cynical but if you expect that your feature request or bug is of highest priority and a must fix within 6 to 8 weeks  you'll be disappointed.

Comment: Well, considering comment is 2nd-class citizen, chat is 3rd-class citizen (and mobile app is 4th). However, it doesn't mean it got less attention, as shown from the last responsive design for mobile chats... Though don't get your hopes high too..

Answer (score 3):

Either here or over on [Meta Stack Exchange](https://meta.stackexchange.com) would be great.

I can guarantee that anything requested in the chat sandbox will not be read (or, at best, remembered), and the support folks behind "contact us" will likely point you back to meta anyway.